# Windows 8 modern UI applications and DirectX... How to draw text?

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx

1. I already have a Direct3d device at my beck and call...
2. I am working on a Windows 8 modern UI application (Metro if you will)

What's the general technique of getting text drawn to the screen?

**Extra points:** Can I do 3d stuff with it too? This is what originally got me here as I started to do some direct2d thing then I thought, but how can I do 3d with direct2d... second of all the d2d create text functions require a handle to a window hwnd and there is no such thing (or it has been abstracted away) in windows 8 metro apps.

Anyone got any good examples or demos I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Regarding your second question you can render your text to a texture and then when you render that texture on screen do 3d stuff with it.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading through this and preparing some code, but I got stuck at the Hwnd part where you must include an hwnd for the CreateHwndRenderTarget... remembering i'm doing a windows 8 application (not desktop program)

Comment: Just found out that the default DirectX project has a TextRenderer supplied in it, going to check that out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Rendering text with DirectWrite and Direct2D it's [relatively simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however, if you want something higher level, you can look into [Drawing Library for Windows Store Apps](http://moderncomponents.com/products/DrawingLibrary/about.php), which wraps raw DirectX calls into some more GDI like.